# Error in executing solr search query from a CloudSolrServer object

Tags: solr, solrj

Here I am trying to fire a solr search query, I am using `CloudSolrServer` class to pass the zookeeper instance and then creating a instance of `SolrQuery` object for search.

```
        CloudSolrServer solr = new CloudSolrServer("HOST_NAME:PORT");

        System.out.println(solr.getZkStateReader());
        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

        solrQuery.set("q", "abc");
        solrQuery.addFilterQuery("type:*");
        solrQuery.set("defType", "edismax");
        solrQuery.set("start", 0);
        solrQuery.set("rows", 10);
        solrQuery.set("qf", "name^10.0 description^5.0");
        solrQuery.addSortField("name_sort", SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);

        QueryResponse response = solr.query(solrQuery);
```

When I am running this I am getting this error:

```
null
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Error executing query
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
    at SolrCloud_Example.main(SolrCloud_Example.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.<init>(ZkStateReader.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.connect(CloudSolrServer.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.request(CloudSolrServer.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
    ... 2 more
```

Could anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: where does `params` come from in the last row ? isn't it should be `solrQuery` ?

Comment: Sorry for that mistake and I have edited it now. But my problem remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced with the same exception. In the result such connection is workable for me: 
 CloudSolrServer solrServer = new CloudSolrServer("c-node3:2181/**solr**");

**/solr** in the end

Answer (score 1):

When using CloudSolrServer, you need to set the default collection value.

Also the CloudSolrServer query() method does not actually take SolrQuery as an argument; it takes SolrParams.  You can create SolrParams from a named list, which SolrQuery can do.

So your code would look something like this:

```
CloudSolrServer solr = new CloudSolrServer("HOST_NAME:PORT");
solr.setDefaultCollection("your_collection");

SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

solrQuery.set("q", "abc");
solrQuery.addFilterQuery("type:*");
solrQuery.set("defType", "edismax");
solrQuery.set("start", 0);
solrQuery.set("rows", 10);
solrQuery.set("qf", "name^10.0 description^5.0");
solrQuery.addSortField("name_sort", SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);

SolrParams params = SolrParams.toSolrParams(solrQuery.toNamedList());
QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
```

You can then use response to get back your results.

Comment: Hi cahilltr, thanks for the response. Now I have set the default collection value but still getting this error :

**org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /live_nodes**

I might be setting the default collection value wrongly, so could you please tell me how to know it or by looking at the error code is there anything else.

Comment: Simanchala, My first thought is to wonder if Zookeeper is actually running; but I'm guessing thats not the issue.  To see all the collections and live nodes that Zookeeper is aware about you can do the following:
`ZkClient = new SolrZkClient(host:port, timeout);
solrZK = solrZkClient.getSolrZooKeeper();
System.out.println(solrZK.getChildren("/live_nodes", true));`
You can do the same with "/collections" to get all the collections.

Comment: Cahilltr, I think there's some problem with my Zookeeper configuration. Because I tried with /live_nodes and /collections and every time it showed similar error message like **org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /live_nodes** or **org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /collections** . I am trying to figure out whether there's any issue in zookeeper solr set up. Anyway thanks.